# The Map to Radiance

Tags: riddle, story

An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #39: Deep Down in the Dungeon 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6478/fortnightly-topic-challenge-39-deep-down-in-the-dungeon-1)

---

In an adventure to find a special area, Radiance, in the mythical land of Geome, our heroes seek out a map to their destinies, and a whole heckuva lotta loot.

As the explorers get through the dungeon that holds the map, they encounter a strange stone statue, blocking what appears to be a doorway.

This stone statue, however, is a guardian, protecting their precious map.

"If you wish to pass me, you must correctly solve my riddle."

The explorers conferred, then agreed.

> I am a knight, though in name not deed.
>   One of my friends can cut a swath through the land,
>   And the other is a master at getting straight to the core.
>   We're fans of desserts, preferably apple or cherry.
>   But alas, I've no time, my work is never done.
>   So, good traveller, what is my name?

Before the others can start to piece together the puzzle, one explorer scowled.

"Oi! That didn't rhyme! What kind of epic, quest blocking riddle doesn't rhyme?!"

"The kind that is made to have you think, not be catchy," was the statue's reply.

The explorers weren't happy with this, but they started to debate the riddle, before finally giving up and heading right back to where they'd started their journey.

Comment: I was having trouble picking other tags without giving the answer and a couple clues away, so if anyone else wants to suggest tags, go for it!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Are you

> Circumference?

I am a knight, though in name not deed.

> Sir Cumference! Haha

One of my friends can cut a swath through the land,

> Diameter

And the other is a master at getting straight to the core.

> Radius

We're fans of desserts, preferably apple or cherry.

> Pi

But alas, I've no time, my work is never done.

> Because you’re a never ending circle

So, good traveller, what is my name?

> Hopefully circumference!

Other hints:

> a special *area*, Radiance as in *Radians*, in the mythical land of Geome as in *geometry*,

Comment: It always baffles me how fast you solve these!

Comment: Right on! There are a couple other clues in the question, too, but you got the core riddle 100%! I wasn't sure if the friends lines would make sense or not, but I guess they did.

Comment: And that's the other clues, wow you're good! (We can also very clearly see what class(es) our explorers skipped or ignored in school!)

Comment: @Kendra are these the extra hints? Also, this resonated because of a childhood [book I read long ago](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sir_Cumference).

Comment: Yep, those were all the extra hints. Great work! (I think I read that book in school myself, so probably why this puzzle came to me so easily too.)

Answer (score 5):

Not to take away from either this fine riddle, or El-Guests answer, but i'd like to point out that an alternate answer that matches the clues would be

> Sir Cle (Circle)

Comment: That's actually a good alternate answer, nice catch!

Comment: I was also thinking this until I reread the riddle; you would have to replace "the" with "my" for it to make sense: One of my friends can cut a swath through my land, 
And the other is a master at getting straight to my core.